# Fantasy book series with main character who has eyes of fire

Tags: story-identification

Found a book series that I have forgotten the title of. MC was a prince who was sent to a monastery to learn the family skill of being emotionless. Family has the trait of fiery eyes. Teacher buries him up to his neck in the ground. Brother trains with elite military group, gains shadow eyes from spider egg during a test underground. Traitors try to assassinate both brothers, kill majority of monastery.